# bash caller builtin stops working from exported function, why?

Tags: bash, introspection, built-in

I have very strange issues using `bash` and exported function to give me a reliable answer to the call of the builtin `caller`.

Here's my setup to illustrate this issue: Bash script `bar` defines and exports function `bar1` and `bar2`. `bar2` calls `bar1`. Bash script `bar` then execute bash script `foo` which will call `bar1`.

The caller builtin will then break **only after the call** of `bar1`. Is this normal ? can you explain why ? can you simplify the following code that exposes the issue ?

To be perfectly clear, here's how to reproduce on your system: Build both file:

```
cd /tmp
cat <<"EOF" > foo 
#!/bin/bash

bar1
EOF
chmod +x foo

cat <<"EOF" > bar 
#!/bin/bash

bar2() {
    echo "$FUNCNAME IN: $(caller 0)" >&2 
} 
export -f bar2

bar1() {
    echo "$FUNCNAME BEFORE: $(caller 0)" >&2
    bar2
    echo "$FUNCNAME AFTER: $(caller 0)" >&2 
}
export -f bar1

./foo
EOF
chmod +x bar
```

You can then fiddle and see:

```
$ ./bar
bar1 BEFORE: 3 main ./foo
bar2 IN: 
bar1 AFTER:
```

I expected (with acceptable variations on the line numbers):

```
$ ./bar
bar1 BEFORE: 9 main ./foo
bar2 IN: 5 bar ./foo
bar1 AFTER: 9 main ./foo
```

Ultimately, my question would be: **how could I circumvent this issue and get the caller** in all cases ?

ADDITIONAL INFO:

- bash version: `4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` from ubuntu package `4.3-14ubuntu1`.

Comment: Interesting question. I'll note that if you fail to export `bar2`, you get the expected error `./foo: line 1: bar2: command not found`, but the final call to `caller` does produce `bar1 AFTER: 3 main ./foo`, so it looks like (perhaps) calling an exported function *from* an exported function has some effect on the call stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/support/?108903) in bash. It was fixed in version 4.4.

In the presence of exported functions, the `BASH_SOURCE` variable is not properly maintained. You can check it by displaying the contents of the `FUNCNAME`, `BASH_SOURCE`, `BASH_LINENO` special variables:

```
cd /tmp
cat <<"EOF" > foo 
#!/bin/bash

bar1 
EOF
chmod +x foo

cat <<"EOF" > bar 
#!/bin/bash

bar2() {
    echo "$FUNCNAME IN: $(caller 0) [${FUNCNAME[@]}] [${BASH_SOURCE[@]}] [${BASH_LINENO[@]}]" >&2 
} 
export -f bar2

bar1() {
    echo "$FUNCNAME BEFORE: $(caller 0) [${FUNCNAME[@]}] [${BASH_SOURCE[@]}] [${BASH_LINENO[@]}]" >&2
    bar2
    echo "$FUNCNAME AFTER: $(caller 0) [${FUNCNAME[@]}] [${BASH_SOURCE[@]}] [${BASH_LINENO[@]}]" >&2 
} 
export -f bar1

./foo
EOF
chmod +x bar
```

Output of `./bar`:

```
bar1 BEFORE: 3 main ./foo [bar1 main] [./foo] [3 0]
bar2 IN:  [bar2 bar1 main] [./foo] [1 3 0]
bar1 AFTER:  [bar1 main] [] [3 0]
```

As you can see, stack frames corresponding to invocations of exported functions aren't added to `BASH_SOURCE`, but whenever a function returns the topmost stack frame is popped.

Note that the `FUNCNAME` variable is not affected by this bug. Thus, if you need only the name of the caller you can obtain it as `${FUNCNAME[1]}`.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you gave me a good answer to how I could get the caller (as asked in bold at the end of my question) by using ``FUNCNAME[1]``. If you include a link to the actual bug report in GNU bash ( http://savannah.gnu.org/support/?108903 ), and tell clearly that this is fixed in 4.4 according to Chet, I won't have any reason not to accept your answer ;-)